# Variable length in PDT Eclipse

Tags: php, xdebug, eclipse-pdt, zend-debugger

Do you know if, under Eclipse Indigo with PDT/xdebug, it is possible to modify the length of the dump of string variables in the **Variable Detail Pane** window ?

I tried to set 0 in **Configure Detail Pane** but failed. Tried also to modify the php.ini with **xdebug.var_display_max_data** without success.

(May be should I try with Zend-Debugger ?)

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29631476/4073877