# Eclipse PDT, XDebug Variable Watch Details only shows 1000 characters

Tags: eclipse, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I am debugging using Eclipse PDT with XAMPP

This question is related to this item:

[Variables viewer on Eclipse debugging truncates the string values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199611/variables-viewer-on-eclipse-debugging-truncates-the-string-values/15250886#15250886)

I am having the same problem as in that link.

I watch a variable and in the Expresssions tab, I can only view about 1000 characters in the "details" window.

If I right click and use 'copy expressions' I get the same 1000 chars.

I have also right clicked the details pane... Max Length and tried setting it to 0 or 30000 (my data is about 20k) and neither changed the max of 1000.

This defeats the whole purpose of me spending 2 days to get Eclipse setup for debugging... If there is no workaround for this, can anyone suggest a PHP debugger that will not have this limitation?

I was going to try the Zend debugger, but saw a video that suggested it uses the same exact Expresssion/Detail pane to show its data... can anyone confirm/deny this?

Thanks!

Comment: Here you can find the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13760096/1769013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried just about everything imaginable... I believe this is a bug in Eclipse that should be fixed, but anyway, I finally just create a new test case that eliminates me needing to debug a 20k piece of data...

Answer (score 2):

In the **Variables** view you right-click on the variable and select **Change value**. If your variable is huge you have to wait a few minutes (in this case Eclipse doesn't respond to commands) but in the end Eclipse will show your variable entirely.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an option to set *no limit* but it is possible to increase the limit within the XDebug config.

Within Eclipse go to

Window -> Preferences -> PHP -> Debug -> Installed Debuggers.

Highlight *XDebug* and click *Configure*.

Within the window that pops up you can see the array depth 
and the max children. Setting those values higher will give you more 
data back about your variables.

[source](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=24812&goto=80399&#msg_80399)